# Python defined function f(*x) failed quiz question

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm coursing Python applied for Data Science in CognitiveClass.ai, i'm at the functions module and did not understand why I failed answering this function-related question.

This is python 3 in a jupyter lab. I thought this code had a mistake but i failed.

This is the question:

> What is the value of c after the following block of code is run ?

```
def f(*x):
    return sum(c)
```

> a) Return the total of a variable amount of parameters
> b) Return the total of a list return the total of a list
> c) The function is not valid

I chose letter c and then B but without success. Letter A is the answer.

I'll be very glad if someone can explain me why did I fail?

kalhan Koul :
For that you need to understand  that in the definition of the function def f(*x):   notation * means if  unknown number of arguments variables  are there then  then   return sum(c) will return the total number of arguments passed. Hence Answer A is valid. It was test of  comprehension of question

Comment: `NameError: global name 'c' is not defined` - I'm guessing `x` and `c` are supposed to be the same variable. Also, the value of `c` after the code is run is not defined, as no code is run: it is a function definition.

Comment: That question makes no sense at all. None of the answers are correct.

Comment: I don't understand why we're downvoting OP for posting a poor test question. It's not like he wrote the test question; he's as confused as we are.

Comment: To be clear [this doesn't work in any sense](https://repl.it/repls/TerrificGlitteringRedundancy). I did include what it should have said to get "a" as the right answer.

Comment: @TemporalWolf No error is raised when running that code. The correct answer is: the same value as before running the code (if any).

Comment: @Goyo That's technically true, but also not an option given, especially given it's pretty clear from the choices of answers they meant what is the returned value from the function.

Comment: Please make sure you copied the question correctly. `A` can only be the correct answer if the second line were `return sum(x)` rather than `return sum(c)`, and elsewhere it does something like `c = f(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @Barmar The question is copied correcty. It is just nonsense and there have been complaints about it in the site for months, maybe years. They just don't care. There is nothing to learn there.

Comment: Hi everybody,

Unfortunately the test question is exactly the same as in the platform. Probably they will check it soon.
Sorry for replying late, I was very busy at my job. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, there might some error with the system. Option a is definitely not the right answer as I too had selected (a) in my first attempt. The function is invalid and the answer should be (c). In my second attempt (following the logic given in some of the comments above) I selected (c) and it came correct. Which it should as the function doesn't initialise c anywhere in the body.

```
def f(*x):
   return sum(c)

complete the function  f  so that it returns the product of  a  and  b  , you the next cell to test the function
```

Gives the above error. Similar error is also given when replacing `c` with `x` . The function is incomplete and invalid.